# jQueryMobile button() vs HTML <button> initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a basic HTML page that uses jQuery Mobile to handle some of the button properties, but when I try and call `$('#theButton').button('disable');`, I'm running into an error that states the button is not initialized (Cannot call button methods prior to initialization). Here's the html page body that has the button:

```
<script>
    $(window).load($("#theButton").button('disable'));
</script>

<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
             <button id="theButton">Click me!</button>
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Can I use `<button>` in conjunction with jQuery Mobile's `.button();` function? And if so how do I initialize the `<button>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the `load()` event with an anonymous function to be executed when the `load` event has fired. Your current code is calling `button('disable')` on an element that does not yet exist in the DOM - hence the error. Try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#theButton").button('disable')
});
```

Comment: So why doesn't it work when the window has loaded? My understanding is that using `$window.load()` fires the `button('disable')` after the DOM has loaded

Comment: That's correct. Note however that the `button()` method is part of jQueryUI which is a separate library to jQuery. You will need to download and reference that in your page, if you haven't already. If you still have problems, check the console for errors (press F12)

Comment: I have both JQmobile and JQ library referenced and downloaded in my code. I'm still unsure of why it has to be an anonymous function rather than what I have

Comment: It's because the anonymous function will be invoked when the `load` event fires, not invoked immediately before the DOM has fully loaded.

Comment: But isn't the `button('disable')` fired after the "sub elements" of window have been completely loaded?

Comment: No. It is fired immediately and the returned value of `button('disable')` (in this case the `#theButton` element) is assigned to the event handler - which will do nothing at all.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for disabling the button on load, may be the below code might help:

```
$(window).load($("#theButton").attr('disabled','true'));
```